# Methods of an interface

Tags: interface, methods, go

Would be correct the next way to implement the methods attached to an interface? (`getKey`, `getData`)

```
type reader interface {
    getKey(ver uint) string
    getData() string
}

type location struct {
    reader
    fileLocation string
    err os.Error
}

func (self *location) getKey(ver uint) string {...}

func (self *location) getData() string {...}

func NewReader(fileLocation string) *location {
    _location := new(location)
    _location.fileLocation = fileLocation
    return _location
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Go you don't need to explicitly say that you are implementing an interface—if a type has everything required by an interface, it can be used via that interface. So you don't need to say `reader` inside the `type location struct`.

See here: http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types

Comment: Indeed, doesn't putting `reader` actually just add an anonymous member to the `location` type, taking up space to not do anything useful?

Answer (score 1):

You've basically done it already. As soon as you give location's getKey and getData methods valid bodies, *location will implement the reader interface. There's no need to do anything more.